# Разделение информации по файлам с помощью gawk

Tags: bash, gnu, awk

Как сделать так, чтобы awk рассматривал новую строку, сравнивал с уже рассмотренными и, если встречал совпадение - дописывал бы в уже существующий файл, а если бы она оказывалась новой - то создавался бы новый файл, куда стали бы дописываться все строки с таким же признаком?

Проблема именно с созданием большого количества файлов, с новыми именами... алгоритм должен их придумывать или называть  эти файлы по имени строки (как мне кажется) иначе я не представляю, как генерировать имена, в которых можно будет ориентироваться.

Если кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой разбиения большого объёма данных, то буду благодарен за подсказку, как это записать в соответствии с синтаксисом awk.

Comment: А почему именно `awk`? Если задание настолько сложное, быстрее будет написать на C++. Или на C#:

    IEnumerable<string> ReadConsoleLines()
    {
        string line;
        while((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
            yield return line;
    }

    foreach (var group in ((filename != null) ? File.ReadLines(filename) : ReadConsoleLines()).GroupBy(l => selector))
        File.WriteAllLines(FileNameFromKey(group.Key), group);

На `awk` можно завести массив уже встреченных строк, и при обнаружении новой строки добавлять в него.

Comment: Потому что работаю на сервере, где терминал на Linux, и из средств, которые мне доступны - это octave и awk. И с массивом попробую так и сделать, только проблема не с поиском строк по отдельному признаку...
35711 35 193 1170 455 456 457 458 459 476 477   
34812 47 193 1170 455 456 190 191 1175 1172 1201    
...  
таких данных у меня на 2 гигабайта, 1-время отправления в секундах, второе время в пути, а дальше номера узлов. Нужно раскидать по разным файлам  пути так, чтобы в одном файле были те, у которых 3 и последнее поля совпадают. (у всех строк 3 поля одинаковые и последние)

Comment: решилось в одну строчку
> awk '{print &0 >> "Origin "$3" Destination "$NF}' filename

Answer (score 1):

ответ из комментария:

---

решилось в одну строчку:

```
$ awk '{print &0 >> "Origin "$3" Destination "$NF}' filename
```